# How do you convert pseudo-code into SQL statements?

Tags: sql

I am taking the free Stanford database course online.  I don't have any DB experience, but have many years of OS programming experience.  Typically, I will flowchart or write out pseudo-code for a particular algorithm before coding it up.  I was wondering if this technique can be used to go from a flowchart or pseudo-code into SQL statements.

Does a loop that iterates over a set match a WHERE clause?  Is this mostly(?) or always(?) true?

How would you map a doubly nested loop into SQL?

Comment: Basic SQL isn't procedural; it has no concept of loops, nor anything equivalent.  So it isn't really meaningful to talk about what a doubly-nested loop maps to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL uses set-based logic (relational algebra/calculus), whereas most programming languages are imperative/procedural (e.g. C#, Java, etc).

If you write set-based logic pseudocode then it should be just as straightforward to translate to SQL as imperative pseudo-code is to translate to C#.

An example of set-based logic pseudo code might be something like this:

```
1.Join book stores and titles over the BookstoreID.
2.Restrict the result of that join to tuples for the book Some Sample Book.
3.Project the result of that restriction over StoreName and StorePhone.
```

If you are trying to convert imperative pseudo-code to SQL (or set-based pseudo-code to C#) it's going to be much more painful.

Comment: I'd argue that it's more than painful; I'd say it's meaningless.

Comment: Well I guess if you have set-based pseudocode you could use LINQ operators to convert it to to C#.  But I agree that converting imperative pseudo-code to SQL is pretty meaningless.  Either you have a set-based algorithm or you don't and you shouldn't be using SQL to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

As Dylan said SQL is designed for set-based logic. However, you can and often in real world situations do loop through these sets.

Basicly, you would store the target result set inside a temp table. Then you would loop through each record in the temp table doing whatever process was necessary.

When you are done, you clean up by dropping the temp tables.

It's not as straight forward as your typical programming language (Pascal,C,etc)

Comment: enh... You can, but to learn SQL (OP's intent) or to take advantage of SQL's power, you should avoid looping code like this if at all possible. Otherwise, cursors can become the crutch propping up mediocre SQL